# Unexpected output when using SUB instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, subtraction

I'm writing a program in MASM to create and subtract three 32-bit integers. My issue is that `9000` subtracted from `30000` appears to result in `27000`, when `21000` is expected. The source is as follows:

```
TITLE Add and Subtract

; This program adds and subtracts 32-bit integers.

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
DumpRegs PROTO

.code
main PROC

    mov eax,50000h          ; EAX = 50000h
    mov ebx,30000h          ; EBX = 30000h
    mov ecx,43h             ; ECX = 43h

    sub eax,10000h          ; EAX = 40000h
    sub ebx,9000h           ; EBX = 21000h
    sub ecx,1h              ; ECX = 42h

    call DumpRegs

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

DumpRegs results in the following:

[image: Unexpected result]

As shown, `EBX`'s value is `00027000` when `0021000` is expected. What's going on here?

Comment: Are you familiar with hexadecimal?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I am. I didn't realize that `h` indicates hexadecimal form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistake hexadecimal numbers for decimal numbers.

`30000h` = `196608d`.

`9000h` = `36864d`.

`196608d` - `36864d` = `159744d`.

`30000h` - `9000h` = `27000h` = `159744d`.